# hg-git Installation: Missing dulwich.errors

Tags: hg-git

I'm having trouble with hg-git.

In my hgrc I have:

```
[extensions]
hgext.bookmarks=
hggit=~/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/hg_gt-0.8.2-py3.5.egg/hggit
```

When I try to hgclone I get:

```
*** failed to import extension hggit from ~/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/hg_git-0.8.2-py3.5.egg/hggit: No module named dulwich.errors.
```

I've already installed dulwich.errors by running easy_install 'dulwich>=0.8.0'.

Can't figure out what's going on.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have to be sure that `hg`, `hg-git` and `dulwich` are installed and running in the same python environment. What is saying `which hg`and `which dulwich`?

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac and no doubt in similar environments, the PYTHONPATH environment variable must also be set properly, e.g. if dulwich is in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ then PYTHONPATH must include that directory.